# Holder pattern approached differences and performance comparisons

Tags: android, performance, testing, adapter

I have seen two ways of doing the same thing, and I do not know what is faster and what is better , and what is the difference . . .

I mean only this few row at the begging are differences and everything else is the same, but still there are two approaches and I do not  understand what is different and which way is faster

case one:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
    View row=super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    ViewHolder holder=(ViewHolder)row.getTag();
```

case two:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
        //of course some checks if the convertView is null, but that is not the point
    ViewHolder holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
```

one more sub-question :-)
How can I test what is faster ? I mean how should I do testing for performance on adapters ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do not understand what is different and which way is faster

What is different is that the first one is chaining to the superclass, and the second one is not.

> How can I test what is faster ? I mean how should I do testing for performance on adapters ?

Use [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html).

Comment: yes with chaining I get reference to the view that's it to the row. And by getting reference to convertView I think is the same think , I mean the same reference or I am wrong ?

Comment: @Luk: When you chain to the superclass, you are getting what the superclass gives you. Whether that is `convertView` or something else is up to the superclass. "And by getting reference to convertView I think is the same think" -- not necessarily, as `convertView` is sometimes `null`.